# android leaked window force close

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I have integrated zxing barcode scanner in my app. When the scanner gets a scan it takes the result and searches an external online database via a async task then opens a new activity based on the results. I am getting a force close that is not consistent, it does not happen every scan, only sometimes so I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting a leaked window error, and only sometimes:

```
09-25 21:02:48.105  24371-24371/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@424b7198 that was originally added here
        android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@424b7198 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:468)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:419)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPreExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:52)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerDataJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerDataJSON.java:111)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerDataJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerDataJSON.java:34)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 21:02:48.265  24371-24371/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:784)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:476)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:182)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:328)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:311)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:74)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:27)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, it looks like your `Dialog` isn't visible when the `AsyncTask` finishes its work. In that case, the call to `dismiss()` will crash the app.

You might try using `Dialog.isShowing()` to avoid the crash:

```
protected void onPostExecute(...) {
    ...
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss(); // or .cancel()
    }
    ...
}
```